# Jquery UI Datepicker beforeShowDay tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-tooltip

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078629/update-datepicker-tooltip-in-beforeshowday) thread about adding tooltip to disabled days on StackOverflow and could not figure out how to add it to my code.

I would be pleased if somebody could help me out.

My code so far:

```
beforeShowDay: function(disabledDates) {
  //Concatenating All dates before they are sent in to beforeShowDay
  var localDateArray = parsedDates.concat(addWeekendToDisabled(), disableToday(), disableTomorrow());

  var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', disabledDates);
  return [localDateArray.indexOf(string) === -1];

},
```

Here is from `Jquery UI Datepicker` official docs beforeShowDay [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow)

> beforeShowDay 
>   
>   Type: Function( Date date )
>   Default: null
>   A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
>   `[0]`: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
>   `[1]`: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
>   `[2]`: an optional popup tooltip for this date

Comment: Events are also disabled on disabled days. Not sure what behavior you are expecting or what implementation issue really is

Comment: See if this demo helps: http://plnkr.co/edit/ncwIPE1m0nYsS3e9MUFS?p=preview

Comment: Ok. So there's no way to get tooltips on disabled date? I wanted to show a tooltip on disabled days that explains why there disabled for booking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an old [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EXdWZa) I made for another question...
The relevant code for your question is below.

**CSS** to re-enable pointer events on disabled dates:

```
pointer-events:initial !important;
```

Then, on `beforeShowDay`, when you return a `false` to disable a date, you also can return a class *(for background-colors, for example AND the pointer-events)*.
You can use that class to attach the right tooltip message, from an array, to the disabled dates.

So to attach the message, which has to be in the `title` attribute of the element, do something like this after the datepicker is instantiated:

```
$(document).find(".ui-state-disabled.red").attr("title",disabledReason[0]).tooltip();
```

---

**Edit**
It looks like after a date is selected, my trick doesn't work...
Because the DatePicker is re-drawn.

So here is the walk-around, using `onSelect` ans a `setTimeout()`:

```
onSelect: function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(document).find(".ui-state-disabled.red").attr("title",disabledReason[0]).tooltip();
        $(document).find(".ui-state-disabled.green").attr("title",disabledReason[1]).tooltip();
    },10);
}
```

It is working in this second [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EXdWZa).

Comment: Nice!!  I will test I out in my solution tonight. I'll get back to you then.

Comment: Tried your solution a bit quickly tonight. Didn't get it to work. Will give it more effort tomorrow.

Comment: Okay! No problem. ;)

Comment: Sorry for the silence . I hade to switch focus from the datepicker to something more urgent today. Will get back to your suggestion soon.  Thanks for your help so far!